# Intellij IDEA separates float value

Tags: intellij-idea

Intell IDEA did this terrible code reformatting

```
    PhysicsComponent physicsComponent = new PhysicsComponent(bodyFactory
            .createBody(e, new Vector2(1, 0.8f), width, "player", BodyType.DynamicBody, false, 0, true, 10000, 0
    .5f, 0, CollisionFilter.CATEGORY_PLAYER, (short) (CollisionFilter.COLLIDES_WITH_ENEMY | CollisionFilter
            .COLLIDES_WITH_GROUND | CollisionFilter.COLLIDES_WITH_BULLET), new Vector2(0, 0), 0, 1))
    ;
```

It even created error by writing 0.5f on multiple lines. How do I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing `Settings-Editor-Code Style-Java-Wrapping and Braces-Chained method calls` to `Chop down if long` instead of `Wrap if long` and `Settings-Editor-Code Style-Java-Wrapping and Braces-Method call arguments` to `Wrap if long` instead of `Do not wrap` seems to improve the formatting.